Attempting to install slither
When following these Instructions I get an Python error that I don't how to deal with.
I have the following installed on my Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
$ python3 --version 
Python 3.12.3
p$ pip3 --version
pip 24.0 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.12)

Then I attempt solc-select.
$ (main) pip3 install solc-select
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

I have attempted a virtual environment but once I leave it I cannot use solc-select.
Then I tried.
$ pip install xyz --break-system-packages
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xyz (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xyz

Any advice?

When you executed the following command:
pip3 install solc-select

Then, it's showing this error:
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

...

So, try executing this command:
sudo apt install python3-solc-select

If python3-solc-select is not available through the standard Ubuntu or Debian repositories, you can install it using pip (Python package manager). Here's how:

Install pip if it's not already installed:
sudo apt install python3-pip


Use pip to install solc-select:
pip3 install solc-select




Does this mean I have to use solc-venv every time I use Slither?
$ python3 -m venv solc-venv
$ source solc-venv/bin/activate
(solc-venv) $ pip3 install solc-select
Collecting solc-select...
...
(solc-venv) $ slither --version
0.10.4
//Different terminal
$ slither
slither: command not found

Yes, if you’re installing it in a virtual environment, then its installation would only be limited to that particular environment as long as it’s activated.

You are trying to install Python packages to your operating system /usr/lib directory.
This is always a bad idea because some of these packages may break your operating system, especially when using sudo pip. Please see this answer for details.
The correct way to install Python packages with pip locally is to create

Create a virtual environment: python -m venv solc-venv
Activate it source solc-venv/bin/activate in your shell
Then run the pip install command
Packages will be installed in solc-venv folder

See this guide for details.
